# Reattaching byobu session creates (group 0)

Tags: byobu, session-restore

When I re-attach a session, it somehow creates some `group 0` and the name of the session gets scrambled up:

```
18:47:49 mcnesium@srv ~$ byobu ls
1: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  3 18:47:49 2018) [203x62] (attached)
18:47:53 mcnesium@srv ~$
```

detaching with `c^a d` and reattaching with `byobu`:

```
18:47:53 mcnesium@srv ~$ byobu ls
1: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  3 18:47:49 2018) [203x62] (group 0)
_1-19138: 1 windows (created Wed Jan  3 18:48:02 2018) [203x62] (group 0) (attached)
18:48:06 mcnesium@srv ~$
```

What is this group thing and how can I make it just re-attach that session?

```
19:13:41 mcnesium@srv ~$ byobu --version
byobu version 5.112
tmux 2.3
```

Answer (score 7):

Its fixed in byobu 5.125. Just create `~/.byobu/.reuse-session`.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/c4136ebfe970c31a785fb87468fa08ab7fd7039e/debian/changelog#L11):

> Allow the dynamic session-creation behaviour to be disabled by
>   creating ~/.byobu/.reuse-session

Also, see the [commit](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/commit/755c0e9f28b3f8ee57d9c7fc166f0bcbe96577db) for the implementation.

Comment: Bro this was frustrating me for days. Thank you!

Comment: This does not work for me after upgrading to ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

It seems that like this changed sometime between Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 and there does not appear to be any option to revert it. However, you can revert it by editing byobu's select-session.py.

On my machine, this was located at: `/usr/lib/byobu/include/select-session.py`

Find the function:

`def attach_session(session):`

Then change the line beginning with `os.execvp("tmux"` to:

`os.execvp("tmux", ["tmux", "-2", "new-session", "-A", "-s", session_name])`

Comment: I am not sure if I want to mess around in byobus code, especially because it's installed via package manager.

Comment: Since there isn't any way to pass an option to byobu that disables this behavior your options are pretty limited -- either change the code to do what you want or live with the behavior. You could try filing a feature request to the byobu maintainers to get an option in a future version, perhaps.

Comment: Revert to old behavior with `touch ~/.byobu/.reuse-session`. [source: byobu changelog](https://github.com/dustinkirkland/byobu/blob/c4136ebfe970c31a785fb87468fa08ab7fd7039e/debian/changelog#L11)